# What's the purpose of the 'name' argument when registering a DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

Simple question.  What's the purpose of the `name` argument when registering a dependency property?  I never see it used anywhere, and it doesn't appear to have to be unique.  Not really sure what the point of it is.

I usually just set it like the following and forget about it:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SupportsPlayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
     nameof(SupportsPlay),
     typeof(bool),
     typeof(Player),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

public bool SupportsPlay {
    get => (bool)GetValue(SupportsPlayProperty);
    set => SetValue(SupportsPlayProperty, value);
}
```

Of course I can't do that with attached properties since they don't have any CLR properties paired with them (by convention).  I was just going to wrap the `DependencyProperty` instead of the CLR property (which means it would have the extra 'Property' suffix) but I ran into a case where two different attached properties in two different classes were called 'Enabled', which made me wonder about that property.

```
public static class ClearSelectionOnLostFocus {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        nameof(EnabledProperty),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ClearSelectionOnLostFocus),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, ClearSelectionOnLostFocus_Changed));

    ...
}
```

So what's the point of the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [Microsoft docs on Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties) convinces me this value is used internally and this naming convention must be followed,

> There are established naming conventions regarding dependency properties that you must follow...
>
> That name must be unique within each registering type. (**"SupportsPlay", the name we are discussing**)
>
> When you create the identifier field, name this field by the name of the property as you registered it, plus the suffix Property. (**SupportsPlayProperty**)
>
> Again, by convention, the name of the wrapper property (**public bool SupportsPlay**) must be the same as the name chosen and given as first parameter of the Register call that registered the property.

And a warning can be found in that page,

> If your property does not follow the convention, this does not necessarily disable all possible uses, but you will encounter several notable issues...
>
> Certain aspects of styles and templates will not work.
>
> Most tools and designers must rely on the naming conventions to properly serialize XAML, or to provide designer environment assistance at a per-property level.
>
> The current implementation of the WPF XAML loader bypasses the wrappers entirely, and relies on the naming convention when processing attribute values.

Comment: I looked all over the place for that.  Good find!  Must've skipped right over it.  Ok, so it looks like what I've been doing for non-attached properties will work, but the attached ones, I *can't* use `name(FooProperty)` because it has the suffix 'property', which the documentation say shouldn't be the case.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure enough, I just ran a test where in an attached property, I passed in 'EnabledProperty' for the name, assigned it in a template, and it crashed in the loader.  I changed it back to just 'Enabled' and the loader worked as expected.  Good to know!

Comment: I think it works in most cases, even if you pick a name like GUID. But the MS tools like XAML designer are using that value internally, we just don’t know when it fails. Intermittent bugs are the most annoying since you need to find a pattern to repro, right? So had better stick to the convention.

Comment: I just used a GUID to test and it seems to be working:)

Comment: It will work if you add it directly, but try adding it via a style targeting a `TextBox` (just use `TargetType`, don't use a key so it applies to all `TextBox` instances), then set it via a `<Setter />` element within the style.  That's what crashed for me when the name wasn't right.  Wouldn't load my window.  Changed it to the expected name and it worked properly.